# select data from a database out of my django app

Tags: python, django, database, select, django-apps

How I can select data from a database that is not inside my django app?

How I should connect my django query to a database that has not been created by my django app?

I have put this code in views.py:

```
def select(request):
    p = user.objects.filter(country='Iran')
    return HttpResponse(p)
```

If the database had been created by django app then there was need to add this part into `views.py`:
(for example)

```
from users.models import user
```

But here what should I do?

P.S:

I'm using pymysl in my django project and have installed lamp in my linux os, and using phpmyadmin. Any more explanation is needed?

Comment: Actually if you just want to connect to database and run a query on it based on the type of your database engine, you can simply use relevant python recipe. Or if want to do different thing you better to add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question and make it more clear.

Comment: What task are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment you made on the other answer,

> First version of our project is in php, we want to migrate to python-django and use the same old database. So we can't create databases again and we should configure our django project to work with existing db.

You want to use an already existing legacy database in django. Django offers the possibility to create models out of your old db ([legacy-databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/legacy-databases/)).

Configure the db settings of your old database. Then you can run `inspectdb` to create django models of your old database:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

Comment: what do you exactly mean by Configure the db settings of your old databasem before running that command?

Comment: the `DATABSES` settings in your settings.py (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/legacy-databases/#give-django-your-database-parameters)

Answer (score 3):

Django supports several databases in one instance.
Also you can manually connect to DB in your python code.
For example:

```
    import psycopg2
    psycopg2.connect(...)
```

Comment: Yes, but I need some info about your task - what do you want to do?

Comment: First version of our project is in php, we want to migrate to python-django and use the same old database. So we can't create databases again and we should configure our django project to work with existing db.

Comment: So you use the same database already prepared by old php app? You will use the same tables without changes in their structure?

Comment: Well, Yes and Yes.

Comment: In this case you can create models (or manually or automatically with inspect as it stated in below). Then just give Django connection parameters:

1. Open settings.py in the root folder of your project.
2. There you have block like this:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
3. Put down correct settings like here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/